# How to convert a list to array when the list has blank array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list

```
A = [np.array([-25.2]), np.array([20.2]), np.array([15.3]), 
     np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([-17.5]), np.array([19.3])]
```

As you can see the list has blank arrays. When I use:

```
A1 = np.array(A)
```

it makes it an object which I cant open in spyder. And if I use:

```
A2 = np.concatenate(A1).astype(None)
```

it does make it an array but cancels the blank array. How should I convert it to an normal array keeping the blank array as well.

Comment: I assume these are numpy arrays

Comment: yes they are numpy arrays

Comment: How's the blank supposed to be represented in the result?  Show the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to have in place of the blank arrays. A numpy array must have the same type, so you can't just have blank. You could fill with NaNs, or zeros etc.

Also, you have no option but to loop through the array.

```
k = [None] * len(a)
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if len(x) == 0:
        k[i] = np.nan
    else:
        k[i] = x

a = np.asarray(k, dtype=float)
```

I suggest you look at what is generating your `a` array in the first place and fix that so you don't have blank arrays.

Comment: Blank array generation is a part of some preprocesing which might exisit for sure. I cant ignore the blank arrays. I would give a try to your method. Thanks

Comment: if the answer was helpful please consider accepting

Comment: I run your code and get an error 'object of type 'int' has no len()'

Comment: apologies, fixed